# Add the Code Format to its own button in the toolbar

Tags: format, tinymce, pre

I'm doing my own TinyMCE toolbar and I want to add the exact same functionality as when you choose Format>Code, but as its own button in the toolbar. Is that possible and how should I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You can add your own button and then have it execute a command.

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('strikeout', {
      icon: 'sourcecode',
      tooltip: "Format as code",
      onAction: function() {
        editor.execCommand('mceToggleFormat', false, 'code');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: And then you need to add the `strikeout` button the toolbar.